# What is the meaning of $\lim_{\Delta(P) \to 0} F(P) = L$ for partitions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Let $[a,b]$ be an interval, and denote by $\mathcal P[a,b]$ the family of all partitions of $[a,b]$, i.e. sets $P = \{ a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = b \}$. 
For some $P \in \mathcal P[a,b]$ set $\Delta(P) := \max_{i=1,\ldots, n} (x_i - x_{i-1})$, i.e. the mesh size. If $F : \mathcal P[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is some function, what does the expression
$$
 \lim_{\Delta(P) \to 0} F(P) = L
$$
mean? Does it mean

i) that for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some partition $P$ such that for each partition $P'$ with $P' \supseteq P$ (i.e. $P'$ refines $P$) we have
$$
 |F(P') - L| < \varepsilon 
$$
or,

ii) that for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for each partition $P$ with $\Delta(P) < \delta$ we have
$$
 |F(P') - L| < \varepsilon
$$
or,

iii) that for each sequence of partitions $\{ P_n \}$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Delta(P_n) = 0$ we have
$$
 \lim_{n\to \infty} F(P_n) = L
$$
where in the last case we have limits over the reals, defined as usual.

So what does it mean? And are all notions written above equivalent?

Comment: Its good that you asked this question. Most students don't know that there is a difference between notions i) and ii) +1 for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means (ii), which is clearly equivalent to (iii).
It's also clear that (ii) implies (i): Given $\delta>0$,
if $P$ has mesh less than $\delta$ and $P'$ is a refinement
of $P$ then $P'$ has mesh less than $\delta$.

But in this generality (i) does not imply (ii). Silly example:
Say $[a,b]=[-1,1]$. Define $F(P)$ by saying that $F(P)=1$ if
$0\in P$, $F(P)=0$ otherwise. Then (i) holds with $L=1$, but (ii)
does not hold; there's no $\delta>0$ such that $\Delta(P)<\delta$ implies that $0\in P$.

(By "$0\in P$" I mean that, in the notation at the top of the OP, there exists $j$ with $x_j=0$.)

---

EDIT: Of course this led to the real question, namely whether (i) implies (ii) for Riemann sums. Of course in that case we need to modify the whole setup somewhat, because a Riemann sum depends on a partition and a choice of points in each interval. A very informal proof that (i) implies (ii) for Riemann sums:

Say $f$ is a bounded function on $[a,b]$, say $|f|\le M$. Suppose $\epsilon>0$, and let $P$ be as in (i).

Given an interval $I$, let $S_I$ and $s_I$ denote the sup and inf of $f$ on $I$. Let $|I|$ denote the length of $I$.

Say $P=(a=x_0<\dots<x_n=b)$. Define $I_j=[x_{j-1},x_j]$. Now if (i) holds we must have $$\sum_{j=1}^n(S_{I_j}-s_{I_j})|I_j|\le\epsilon.$$

Now say we have another partition $P'=(a=y_0<\dots<y_m=b)$ with mesh less than some small number $\delta$. Let $J_k=[y_{k-1},y_k]$. For $j=1,\dots,n$ let $$E_j=\{k:J_k\subset I_j\},$$and let $$F=\{1,2,\dots,m\}\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^nE_j.$$Now if $k\in E_j$ then $S_{J_k}\le S_{I_j}$ and $s_{J_k}\ge s_{I_j}$; hence $$\sum_{k\in E_j}(S_{J_k}-s_{J_k})|J_k|\le (S_{I_j}-s_{I_j})|I_j|,$$hence $$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k\in E_j}(S_{J_k}-s_{J_k})|J_k|\le \epsilon.$$On the other hand if $k\in F$ then there exists $j$ so that $x_j$ lies in the interior of $J_k$. Hence $F$ has at most $n$ points, and so if $\delta$ is small enough then $$\sum_{k\in F}(S_{J_k}-s_{J_k})|J_k|\le n(2M)\delta\le\epsilon.$$Add it all up and you get $$\sum_{k=1}^m(S_{J_k}-s_{J_k})|J_k|\le2\epsilon.$$

Comment: Ah okay, thank you! Does (i) implies (ii) if we restrict the functions $F$, i.e. the ones that could be written as Riemann-Sums of some functions $f$? What I mean is just consider functions $F$ that could be written as $F(P) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i) (x_i - x_{i-1})$ for some function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ and partition $P = \{ a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = b \}$? I do not see that your function could be written that way...

Comment: @Stefan Yes, (i) implies (ii) for Riemannn sums. See edit...

Comment: Very good explanation for the equivalence of i) and ii) for Riemann sums. I prefer the definition i) for Riemann sum as the concept of adding new points to make a partition finer seems much simpler to me. +1

Comment: In your first lines by using (i) on $\varepsilon > 0$ we could get $\sum_{j=1}^n |S_{I_j} - s_{I_j}| |I_j| < 2\varepsilon$, as they are both with and $\varepsilon$-interval around some fixed value $L$. Then in your derivation you just show that the difference between upper and lower sums is always arbitrary small for some $\delta$ which is small enough, but that does not imply that these upper and lower sums are also around this same limit $L$, but that I guess could be found in textbook's, and as you said your proof is quite informell, so I guess I got the point. Thank you!

Comment: @Stefan Hugely "informal": I claimed to be saying something about Riemann sums, and there were no explicit Riemannn sums appearing anywhere in the proof, just those upper and lower Darbouxish sums. Was assuming we could translate from one to the other as in those textbooks you mention - upper and lower sums are often easier to deal with.